# Changing response IP Address on runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

## Dinamically switching response ip address(c#)

I am trying to make a small script in ASP.NET(C#) that interface with external RESTapi service,
the problem is that i want the script to switch response ip address after 10(for example) requests,
i bought 12 static IP addresses to my server and binded all of them to the network card and to the iis application.
i searched all over the internet and didnt found even a small example of how to do this, is it possible at all?
the script should look like this(only for example):

```js
string[] ips = {"1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","3.3.3.3",....};
int i = 0,sel=0;
foreach(var request in requests)
{
 if(i % 10 == 0) sel ++;
 if(sel == ips.length) sel = 0;
 doREST(request,ips[sel]);
 i++;
}
```

### Another idea

i Thought about another idea, maybe its better to do a request to my server himself, for example from:

> example.com/edit/post/12

to:

> 1.1.1.1/do-rest/12

and than to:

> 2.2.2.2/do-rest/12

the problem with this is that it could be high amount of request inside the server on high traffic.

Thanks!

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 + will have load balancing feature by default. To how to use it, [You can read it here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725691.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Truly, the way you are thinking it can't be the right way of balancing the load. You need a load balancing software.

Load balancing software is a networking solution responsible for distributing incoming traffic among multiple servers hosting the same application. It balances application requests across multiple servers.